# How do I get the boot manager to give me an option to choose from which os I want to boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a computer in which Windows 10 is installed.Recently I have installed  Ubuntu on it.The boot manager automatically boots my computer with Windows.Now I want the boot manager to give me a boot menu each time I login automatically so I can choose from which OS I want to boot my computer.How can I do that? My computer has Ubuntu and Windows on it.

Comment: hi check this out https://www.linuxtechi.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Check on your BIOS/EFI settings. It must be set the priority of booting in **Windows boot manager**.

You have to set that to **Ubuntu** or your **hard disk** (i.e. ATA...).

Comment: I finally understood what you meant and found the priority list of OS managers and set the Ubuntu boot manager[Grub] to number 1 and my problem was solved.You helped me a lot.